# Не добавляется значение в dict

Tags: python, telebot, dict

Значения не добавляются в директорию.

```py
ideas = ['user_ideas:']
dct = defaultdict(list)
```

```
def user_write(message):

    idea = message.text
    dct['user_ideas'].append(idea)
    markup4 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    write = types.KeyboardButton("Записать ещё мысль")
    thing = types.KeyboardButton(" Вспомнить мысли")
    back = types.KeyboardButton("❌ Вернутся в главное меню")
    markup4.add(write, thing, back)
    msg = client.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Ваша мысль: {idea}\nУспешна записана в Yaжедневник.", reply_markup=markup4)
    client.register_next_step_handler(msg, user_answer)
```

Вывод происходит в следующей функции:

```
    elif message.text == " Вспомнить мысли":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        write = types.KeyboardButton("Записать ещё мысль")
        back = types.KeyboardButton("❌ Вернутся в главное меню")
        markup.add(write, back)
        msg = client.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ваш список мыслей :{" ".join(dct)}', reply_markup=markup)
        client.register_next_step_handler(msg, user_answer)
```

Но по итогу при выводе директории отображается лишь её ключ и ничего не добавляется

```
Yaжедневник, [01.08.2022 16:09]
Запишите всё, что душе угодно ! Даже самая маленькая мысль может напомнить вам о самом дорогом на свете.

User, [01.08.2022 16:09]
Привет дневник!

Yaжедневник, [01.08.2022 16:09]
Ваша мысль: Да
Успешна записана в Yaжедневник.

User, [01.08.2022 16:09]
 Вспомнить мысли

Yaжедневник, [01.08.2022 16:09]
Ваш список мыслей :user_ideas
```

Как сделать так , чтобы добавлялись значения которые указывает дописывает сам пользователь и отображались при вызове функции корректно.

Comment: Хоть от Json избавились, уже прогресс:)

Comment: Проблема была решена! А вместе с ней и создалась другая. Я случайно создал директорию с заметками для всех пользователей и когда пользователь запрашивает его заметки, он получает заметки всех пользователей. Нужно придумать , как реализовать что-то на подобии этого my_dictionary[user_personal_id]. @СергейШ

Comment: "Проблема была решена!" Молодец! Можешь когда захочешь :) В телеграмме каждый пользователь имеет уникальный ID и каналы тоже. Как извлешь этот ID поищите в интернете. "на подобии этого my_dictionary[user_personal_id]" не обьязательнo, можно пристроит к тому что уже есть ideas = {"id_user":{'user_ideas":[]. "name": "Misha", city: "Omsk"}}  будеть ваша первая база данных :)